# Android app can't send request through NGROK on real device

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, retrofit, ngrok

I know there are a lot of similar question but mine is particular.
I have Android app using a NodeJS Back-end on localhost:3000. In order to test my app on my real device (and other friend so far from me), I'm using Ngrok to redirect requests. 
Then, on Postman, I can reach the BackEnd through Ngrok. When I run my App on Android Studio emulator, requests sent from the app can reach the BackEnd through Ngrok. On my real device, when I open a browser and send /GET I can also reach BackEnd through Ngrok. But, when I run my app on my real device (I installed the apk-debug generated from Android Studio), the request doesn't have any response and I can't see Ngrok receiving it in the logs, neither the Back-end.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            //.baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
            .baseUrl("http://1e2b8b83.ngrok.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Great job laying out the tests you've done!  Now you need to complete the process of posting here by placing a question at the end of all the writing you did ...

Also include some log files from the debug of the apk-debug ... head over the Android Studio documentations to figure out how to get them ...

Answer (score 1):

I found it : 
Android P version is blocking requests to HTTP servers. We should either communicate to an HTTPS server or to use a quick fix. The fix then is to create an xml file with the following content :

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">2b8e18b3.ngrok.io</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
</domain-config>
```

then add it in the MANIFEST Application balise as follow :

```
 <application
...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
... />
```

Big thanks to the guy who wrote this article : 
https://medium.com/mindorks/my-network-requests-are-not-working-in-android-pie-7c7a31e33330

Comment: I tried this solution but still facing the same issue. :(